# Can you identify telepathically received messages sent through spells like Sending as magical via Detect Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

An enemy casts Sending to communicate with a player from far away. In this example, the player character doesn't know anything about the Sending spell and he might think he is just hearing voices or going crazy.

Another player casts Detect Magic to scan the area. Can this player detect the presence of the telepathic message inside the first players head via Detect Magic as an evocation spell?

Comment: In the future, if a question of yours is closed, we should work to get your post reopened rather than deleting and reposting [to get around question closure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176370/62294).